# How to get YouTube Data API response in real time and proactively?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

With [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) we can parse comments from a certain video, reply to these comments, modify and delete our comments etc. But in this aforementioned documentation I didn't find the way to fetch the user comments in **real-time**. So the situation is like - apart from fetching comments when the API is called, I want the API to proactively update me with most recent changes if any new comment arrives or any modification or deletion happens. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to find out of there have been comments its to poll the API and check every now and then.  There are no push notifications for comments if that's what you are looking for.

Push notifications only work for.

> [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications)
>
> - uploads a video
> - updates a video's title
> - updates a video's description

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to get only the comments which are new or have any modifications (without fetching all the comments again)? Any better way to manage it?

Comment: Not as far as i know this is going to require polling on your part https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list

Comment: I understood, but in this way I have to parse the comments or the replies to the comments based on `id` or `parent_id` respectively. After fetching all of them I have to find out if there is any change occurred. But I want to avoid this overhead, so how to tell which will be my desired "part" beforehand, i.e, how to know which comments to fetch before actually fetching them? Again is there any way to achieve this by making use of `etag`? Or probably in some other ways?...Would you explain?

Comment: As far as i know using Etag will only tell you if something has been modified not if something new has been added.   You understand this is a free API and its very limited in what it can do.